# How overlay network has led to the other network virtualization techniques

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan, vpn, sdn

When taking about virtualization in computer networks, can we argue that `Overlay Network` is the baseline of plenty of virtual networking techniques such as VPN, vLAN, peer-to-peer, and currently SDN?

My point here is that I think the introduction of overlay network concept led to have other types of network virtualization as I stated.

I wanted to share this argument to see how strong it is. Thank you

Comment: Sadly, questions whose answers generate opinions, rather than objective answers are off-topic or this forum.  You are welcome to discuss this in chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overlay as in a layer is not new.  IP is layered on top of link layer technologies such as Ethernet.  IP GRE tunneling used to be discouraged because of the overhead, sometimes doubling the bandwidth required to send the same message if the message was small.  With encryption a requirement for some, encrypted tunneling like IPSec VPN's became popular.

These days bandwidth is cheap and abundant so we have tons of overlay technologies deployed to fix various needs.  As a result, the number of network engineers with practical knowledge of link layer networking is decreasing - they simply overlay over overlay over overlay.  That's my opinion.